# Tabs displayed incorrectly when populated from array

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to create some tabs like in [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp). I can display hard coded tabs no problem but when I try to populate the tabs from a list, they are displayed incorrectly.

Code and image below.

tabsv2.html

```
<template>

    <!--Not Working-->
    <ul class="tab" repeat.for="name of collection">
        <li><a href="#" id="${name}" class="tablinks" click.delegate="openTab($event, name)">${name}</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div repeat.for="name of collection">
        <div id="${name}" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>${name}</h3>
            <p>${name} is a capital city. </p>
        </div>
    </div>


    </br></br>

    <!--Working-->
    <ul class="tab">
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" click.delegate="openTab($event, 'London1')">London</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" click.delegate="openTab($event, 'Paris1')">Paris</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" click.delegate="openTab($event, 'Tokyo1')">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="London1" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>London</h3>
        <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Paris1" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Paris</h3>
        <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="Tokyo1" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>Tokyo</h3>
        <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

tabsv2.js

```
export class tabsv2 {

    collection = ["London", "Dublin", "Paris"];


    openTab(evt, cityName) {
        // Declare all variables
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

        // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        console.log("Display place:");
        console.log(cityName);

        // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
}
```

[image: tabs not formatted correct;y]

The first set of tabs, populated from an array, are displayed vertically and are unclickable. The hard coded ones are displayed correctly.

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

**Update**

As Fabio suggested, I moved the `repeat.for` so it looks like this:

```
<ul class="tab">
    <li repeat.for="name of collection"><a href="#" id="${name}" class="tablinks" click.delegate="openTab($event, name)">${name}</a></li>
</ul>

<div repeat.for="name of collection">
    <div id="${name}" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>${name}</h3>
        <p>${name} is a capital city. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The tabs are correctly displayed horizontally but still do not expand when clicked:

[image: updated image]

Comment: You've put the `repeat.for` in the `<ul>`. I think you should put it in the `<li>`

Comment: Oh you're right. They are displayed correctly now but they are still un-clickable. I'll update post now

Comment: You shouldn't use a parent div to use `repeat.for`. You should do this:  `<div id="${name}" class="tabcontent" repeat.for="name of collection">`

Comment: @FabioLuz Thanks for suggestion. I have changed the code but they are still non-functional

Answer (score 0):

Had a mistake in my code:

```
<a href="#" id="${name}" class="tablinks" click.delegate="openTab($event, name)">${name}</a>
```

Should have been:

```
<a href="#" class="tablinks" click.delegate="openTab($event, name)">${name}</a>
```